# Unable to iterate over a single Map using two iterators

Tags: java, exception, iterator

I have one `Map<Integer, List<string>>`, I have to remove the key according to my requirement.

So I am using two iterator but a `ConcurrentModificationException` exception is thrown:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        Map<Integer, List<String>> lMap = new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>();
        lMap.put(95, Arrays.asList("Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You"));
        lMap.put(13, Arrays.asList("Adhar", "kumar", "patra"));
        lMap.put(76, Arrays.asList("sivam", "Panday"));
        Set<Entry<Integer, List<String>>> detailEntrySet = lMap.entrySet();
        // Set<Entry<Integer, List<String>>> detailEntrySet1 = lMap.entrySet();
        Iterator<Entry<Integer, List<String>>> iterator = detailEntrySet.iterator();
        Iterator<Entry<Integer, List<String>>> iterator1 = detailEntrySet.iterator();
        System.out.println("******************:=" + i);
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            List<String> value = iterator.next().getValue();
            if(value.stream().anyMatch(a->a.contains("Are"))) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }

        while (iterator1.hasNext()) {
            List<String> value = iterator1.next().getValue();
            if(value.stream().anyMatch(a->a.contains("patra"))) {
                iterator1.remove();
            }
        }

    }
```

[image]

Why I am getting this exception?

Comment: Don’t post screenshots. Include source code and exception as text. Besides that, modifying a collection invalidates existing iterators (except the one you used for the modification). But why are you creating the second iterator before the first loop? Create it when you need it and not earlier. Or use an idiomatic `for` loop: `for(Iterator<Entry<Integer, List<String>>> iterator = detailEntrySet.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) { … }` Then, you don’t even need another variable name for the second loop.

Comment: Besides that, you surely meant `a.equals("Are")` instead of `a.contains("Are")` and likewise for the `"patra"` string, as there are no substring matches. Then, you can simply use `lMap.values().removeIf(list -> list.contains("Are"));` and `lMap.values().removeIf(list -> list.contains("patra"));`, without dealing with iterators. But what’s the point of doing exactly the same thing four times?